# How do I get OpenSSL to populate the EC_POINT in my EC_KEY?

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, elliptic-curve

Sample code:

```
void BN_println_fp(char* name, BIGNUM* value) {
    if (value != NULL) {
        printf("%s: ", name);
        BN_print_fp(stdout, value);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void populatePublicKey(int curveName) {
    EC_GROUP *ecgrp = EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name( curveName );
    EC_KEY* eccKey = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(curveName);
    EC_KEY_set_asn1_flag(eccKey, OPENSSL_EC_NAMED_CURVE);
    EC_KEY_set_enc_flags(eccKey, 0);
    if (EC_KEY_generate_key(eccKey) != 1) {
        return NULL;
    }
    EC_POINT *pub = EC_POINT_new( ecgrp );
    const BIGNUM* pbn = EC_KEY_get0_private_key(eccKey);
    EC_POINT_mul( ecgrp, pub, pbn, NULL, NULL, NULL );
    EC_KEY_set_public_key( eccKey, pub);
    BN_println_fp("X", pub->X);
    BN_println_fp("Y", pub->Y);
    BN_println_fp("Z", pub->Z);
}
```

The output is unpredictable, but invariably involves a panic due to accessing invalid pointers in pub.  But if I instead print out the key using the following function, I get a public key printed.

```
void printECDSA(EVP_PKEY *pkey) {
    BIO* fp = BIO_new_fp(stdout, BIO_NOCLOSE);
    EVP_PKEY_print_public(fp, pkey, 3, NULL);
    EVP_PKEY_print_private(fp, pkey, 3, NULL);
    BIO_free(fp);
}
```

What gives?

Comment: Any help on this one would be greatly appreciated.  I've been unable to figure out how to get those fields populated.